# Python unittest for a very long string

Tags: python

I'm currently writing a unit test for a python function that formats the contents of .txt file as a list, like so:

```py
    def list(self):
        """Show all items in the todo file."""
        with open(self.todo_file) as f:
            items = f.readlines()
        number_width = len(str(len(items)))
        for i, line in enumerate(items):
            print(f"{i+1:{number_width}} {line.strip()}")
        print(f"---\n{len(items)} item(s)")
```

Should output a list like this:

```bash
  1 Hello, World!
  2 Begin plans for world domination
  3 Improve Python todo project
  4 Hello, World!
  5 Begin plans for world domination
  6 Improve Python todo project
  7 Hello, World!
  8 Begin plans for world domination
  9 Improve Python todo project
 10 Hello, World!
 11 Begin plans for world domination
 12 Improve Python todo project
 13 Hello, World!
 14 Begin plans for world domination
 15 Improve Python todo project
 16 Hello, World!
 17 Begin plans for world domination
 18 Improve Python todo project
```

I would like to write a unit test, testing the indentation for larger numbers, for example:

```bash
  1 Hello, World!
  2 Begin plans for world domination
  3 Improve Python todo project
  ...
 28 Something Else
 29 I like indentation
  ...
999 Even with very large numbers
```

Notice how the indentation remains in line regardless of the number of entries, this is obviously because I've set a dynamic width in the formatting, which i'd like to write a test for.

Currently, my test mocks the contents of the .txt file with a string, and then checks how the output is formatted:

```
def test_a_long_list(self):
    """Test that we can show a long list going into double figures"""
    with patch(
        "todo.open",
        mock_open(
            read_data="One (2022-04-25)\nTwo (2022-04-25)\nThree (2022-04-25)\nFour (2022-04-25)\nFive (2022-04-25)\nSix (2022-04-25)\nSeven (2022-04-25)\nEight (2022-04-25)\nNine (2022-04-25)\nTen (2022-04-25)\nEleven (2022-04-25)"
        ),  
    ):
        Handler().done()
    expected = dedent(
        """\
         1 One (2022-04-25)
         2 Two (2022-04-25)
         3 Three (2022-04-25)
         4 Four (2022-04-25)
         5 Five (2022-04-25)
         6 Six (2022-04-25)
         7 Seven (2022-04-25)
         8 Eight (2022-04-25)
         9 Nine (2022-04-25)
        10 Ten (2022-04-25)
        11 Eleven (2022-04-25)
        ---
        11 item(s) done
        """
        )
        self.assertPrinted(expected)
```

How could I write a test for a larger .txt file, containing thousands of entries, without writing a gigantic string variable?

Comment: Would be acceptable if your function returned (or yielded) its results instead of printing them? Then it would be easier to check, say, the first and last lines, if you wanted to do that.

Comment: Or, pass the output file as an argument, and print to that instead of standard output. (The output file can default to standard output, but you can pass a `StringIO` object instead.) While you are at it, consider taking a file-like object as an argument as well to read from, instead of opening a file in the function.